# Upload Access to SharePoint

Tags: microsoft-access, sharepoint

Access 2007 ribbon -

1. "Move to SharePoint"
2. My Network Places
3. Open the file on the SharePoint to save it in, name it, click ok.  I get a msg "Plase save to document library. So I go to shared documents on the SharPoint create a file, save the database and I get an error: "Microsoft Office Access cannot perform the export operation"....  Why not?  the steps are simple, but this msg tells me nothing as to why it cannot save it.   Could someone pls help me get this Access db on the Sharepoint so the users can start using it?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, hit submit to soon...  Steps 1-3 just show what I'm doing..

Comment: Is this your front end to SQL Server? Moving to Sharepoint means "moving your Access data tables" to Sharepoint, if I'm not mistaken. If you don't have any, you don't have anything to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe SharePoint does not allow Acess DBs as a permitted upload unless changes are made to the permitted list on the site.  Are you the site admin?  If not, check with them to see if Access DB files are permitted or not.  Some files like EXEs are not permitted to avoid folks trying to run them directly from the site.  Assume same applies to the DB as trying to open would present a challenge.

Comment: I have full access to the site but I'm not the actual admin.  With that said, how do I allow users to use the database, assuming I cannot upload the entire database?

Comment: First thought is back to the file share.

Comment: Not the direction I was hoping to go... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds this post like I did. A way round it is to create the tables in SharePoint first. Then from SharePoint open in Access (Actions view in access).

Then create the forms and queries from the linked tables. If the database is already created just make sure you name all the lists and columns the same as your old tables and you should be able to copy the forms from the old database to the new linked one and they still work.